# STM (Software Transactional Memory) C++ state of the art

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++, stm, transactional-memory

I have a question about state of the art of the STM ( Software Transactional Memory ) in C++.
I read on cppreference site ([transactional_memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory)) that this is an experimental feature, but it also say that the page is under costruction, so my question is:

**Is this feature now supported by the standard? (example c++17 or c++20)**

If not yet, the cppreference page says:

> This technical specification is supported by GCC as of version 6.1 (requires -fgnu-tm to enable). An older variant of this specification was supported in GCC as of 4.7.

**Is this feature supported also by newer GCC versions?**

Comment: _Transactional Memory N4514 6 (no atomic_cancel) -fgnu-tm __cpp_transactional_memory >= 201505_ Found on [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Answer (score 1):

The phrases "STM", "software" and "transactional" do not occur in the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf) (working draft, N4849, 2020-01-14). So I think it's safe to say that it's not supported by the standard.

As for GCC, `man g++` for version 10.2.0 says:

> `-fgnu-tm`
>
> When the option `-fgnu-tm` is specified, the compiler generates code for the Linux variant of Intel's current Transactional Memory ABI specification document (Revision 1.1, May 6 2009).  This is an experimental feature whose interface may change in future versions of GCC, as the official specification changes.  Please note that not all architectures are supported for this feature.
>
> For more information on GCC's support for transactional memory,
>
> Note that the transactional memory feature is not supported with non-call exceptions (-fnon-call-exceptions).

The second paragraph really ends mid-sentence. Maybe they meant to link to [the GCC wiki page on TransactionalMemory](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TransactionalMemory).

In any case, it seems like support in GCC has been present in some form or other since version 4.7.